# Use PHP form submit to add JSON with incremented operator

Tags: php, json

I'm using a form to submit data and store it as JSON in a file. No I want to add a new line of info called 'age', and have PHP incrementing it as data is stored... first form submit would have 'age':0, 2nd would have 'age':1 and so on.

```
$age = 0;

$formdata = array(
    'job'=> $_POST['job'],
    'company'=> $_POST['company'],
    'city'=> $_POST['city'],
    'category'=> $_POST['category'],
    'type'=> $_POST['type'],
    'description'=> $_POST['description'],
    'age'=> $age++
);
```

I have this above, but it keeps storing data as 'age':0, no incrementing. How should I fix it?

Comment: Increment `$age` before trying to assign it to an element.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Like this? $age = 0++; //// 'age'=> $age

Comment: `$age = 0; $age++; $formdata = ...'age' => $age);`

Comment: What is the incremental criterion?

Comment: Variables in a PHP script (and, actually, any script for that matter) do not keep their value between script executions. In other words, when your user submits a form, PHP will not by itself "remember" what value `$age` used to have last time around.

Comment: @TerraPass is there anyone I could force it to remember the last value of $age?

Comment: To implement something like this you need to store the value of `$age` in some persistent storage, be it a file on the server, a database or a cookie on the user's device (though, in the last case it would be counted for each user separately) and read it every time a script needs to be executed.

Comment: @TerraPass - too bad... I wanted to implement an ordering feature in my job board app. Thank you, tho.

Comment: @TerraPass Is there a way to store a submission's date/time? I could use it to sort entries the same way I would before.

Comment: @PauloGabriel Of course. If you are only interested in sorting, it should be enough for you to save a timestamp, see [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). One issue, though, is that `time()` returns timestamp in seconds, so if several users submit their forms in the same second, they'll have the same `$age` value stored. So, it might be better to use [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) - it has microsecond precision, which makes such a collision unlikely.

Comment: @TerraPass I'll give it a try! I'll let you know.

Comment: @TerraPass for some reason when I used angular to printed the `time()` value it return Jan 17, 1970. I read more about it and found this `$current_date = gmDate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");`  - worked like a charm (although there might be the same problem you mention `time()` could have).